# iOS overriding action when link is clicked

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ipad, http

Is it possible to do something like Android to register the protocol+domain
i.e. `http://mydomain.com/<querystring>` and make my app as the default application when the link is clicked. The reason why I want to do this is I want to have the portability of the this link. I can either open it up on browser on a PC or open my app if it is triggered on an iOS device.

I know I can always do my own redirect on the website `http://mydomain.com -> myprotocol://`, but the user experience is bad as it will pop safari then pop my app.

Any suggestion?

Comment: myprotocol:// is basically the only way to go. You can only intercept urls with non http/https protocols on iOS, unfortunately. The only "alternative methods of launching an app" right now are custom protocols, push notifications and smart app banners.

Answer (score 0):

URL Schemes is what you are looking for.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).

Comment: I am looking for a way to override http/https protocol, so that I can open it up on a non-ios environment too.